# MySQL: Updating Counted Rows

Tags: mysql

I have 5 rows in a database. I want to count accepted rows which are set to one and are 4 in a table and then update page row to that amount.
Could you correct my query?

So I thought an answer to my question.

```
$count = mysqli_result(mysqli_query($con1, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `wishes` WHERE `accepted`=1"));
mysqli_query($con1,"UPDATE `wishes` SET `wishes`.`page`='".$count."' WHERE id='".$uid."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your table name as wishes and field page to be updated with count(amount) field where count(accepted) field = 1 and id is 5,
the query should look like this :

```
update wishes set page = count(amount) where count(accepted)=1 and id=5
```

Please be more clear with your question if this is not the expected query.

Comment: I have 5 rows in a database. I want to count accepted rows which are set to 1 and currently are 4 in a table and then update page row to that amount.